# Multiple parameters onclick event

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.6

I am getting syntax error from my code when passing multiple parameters with onclick event. When it reaches three parameters I get the error. My code has no issue with localhost and is working as expected. Thanks you for the help.

Heres my code:

`onclick="editPost({{$post->id}},'{{$post->title}}','{{$post->description}}','{{$post->shortDesc}}','{{$post->caption}}','{{$post->author}}')"`

Comment: Does `{{$post->description}}` or one of the others result in a string that contains apostrophes?

Comment: Yes @Xufox. Upon checking it does have apostrophes.

Comment: Then maybe switch your quotes from single to double and viceversa: `onclick='editPost({{$post->id}},"{{$post->title}}","{{$post->description}}","{{$post->shortDesc}}","{{$post->caption}}","{{$post->author}}")'`

Comment: Still the same error @andriusain . I have tried escaping the string with addslashes() and it is working in localhost. But in live host I'm still getting the error.

Comment: What error did you get ? Did you make sure that all results have escaping the string ?

Comment: I get this "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token". Yes I have tested it in localhost and there is no error. Only in live host I get this error.

Comment: this code works in localhost but not in live host : onclick="editPost({{$post->id}},'{{ addslashes($post->description)}}')"

Comment: Its the caching maybe?

Comment: Thank you guy for all the help. I have found the solution using regex. '{{ preg_replace( '/\r|\n/', '', addslashes($yourstring))  }}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recheck my data and notice that I also have new lines. So to escape new lines and qoutes I have use this code:

```
'{{ preg_replace( '/\r|\n/', '', addslashes($yourstring))  }}'
```

Thank you guys for all the help! :)